# GridView looks different on Android Nougat

Tags: android, gridview

I have an app with a GridView adapter which displays images in gallery-like manner, 3 on a row.

The adapter I wrote makes the grid looks perfect on all resolutions, and it works perfectly on Android 4,5 and 6.

However, when I run the app on a Android 7 device, the items on the grid overlap.

Same devices, same hardware, same resolution/dpi. 
Why is that and what can I do? What's different on Android 7?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. Beyond that, use Android Studio's layout inspector to try to determine what is different.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this.
i'm calculating the dpWidth and dpHeight like this:

```
 float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
 float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

i had problems with gridView and i realize that the density of the mobile phone was 4. so my solution was change gridView numColumns to 4 instead of 3.

If you really want to use 3 you have to calculate it better.

Hope this help you.